# Calling QPluginLoader::staticInstances from the constructor of a class instantiated as a static local crashes

Tags: c++, qt

I have a singleton class for the purpose of loading Qt plugins instantiated as a static local:

```
LibraryManager* LibraryManager::instance()
{
    static LibraryManager manager;
    return &manager;
}
```

I'm getting "__cxa_guard_acquire(): initializer for function local static variable called enclosing function" in the console whenever `QPluginLoader::staticInstances()` is hit in the constructor of LibraryManager. What does this mean exactly, and how can I fix this?

Comment: So your instance() method is actually declared as static in the header file?

Comment: Yes, LibraryManager is a singleton class. Its constructor loads Qt plugins using QPluginLoader.

Comment: Google suggests that this is mac specific. Add a tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was just a brain error.

My plugin class was inheriting from the class actually used by library clients (which calls into manager, which instantiates plugins, whose constructors call manager... you can see where that leads), when it should have inherited from a different class that only calls manager from member functions (not its constructor).

tl;dr I typed the wrong class name, but didn't think I did so I dismissed that part of the code as possibly containing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this source](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libcppabi/libcppabi-14/src/cxa_guard.cxx), you have somehow managed to recurse back to the same function local in the same thread. Isn't your library manager a plugin itself, by chance? :)

I don't know what it means, but my gut feeling is that an oldschool singleton could fix it. That is having a pointer to instance as class member initialized to null and do a lazy check in instance() call. I understand that it requires implementing a static release method and finding a proper place to call it. But it would bypass the function local, which is what your error message complains about.

Comment: The strangest part is that simply calling QPluginLoader::staticInstances is what is causing the call back to that instance() method.

Comment: I'm trying to bundle static plugins into a dynamic library which is in turn used by an application.